# A relative clause with a {subject, object} pronoun

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

This grammatical case has been bothering me for quite a while already.
On a forum, there is a post.

> Alright, now I get it. The leader can be assigned when you reach a required rank and upgrade a unit to the commander.
>   After that, there is clear indication who is the captain during the selection for a mission.

The part that bothers me is `who is the captain`.
I am not sure if it's correct for `who` to be a subject because `who is the captain` sounds like a question to me.

I understand that the sentence can be rephrased like `there's clear indication who the captain is`, so `who` becomes an object.
However instead, I want to be finished with the stated question, and the question is:

Is the second sentence of the quote grammatically correct?

Comment: There's no relative clause: "who" is interrogative in your example, not relative. Subordinate interrogatives (embedded questions) normally don't have inversion, so one would expect "After that, there is clear indication who the captain is during the selection for a mission", where "the captain" is subject.

Comment: @BillJ, did I understand it correctly that the original second sentence is grammatically correct but better be rephrased?

Comment: It's grammatical. Stylistically, I'm more bothered by *there is clear indication* (as opposed to *there is **a** clear indication*) than by *who is the captain* (as opposed to *[of] who the captain is*). Personally, I'd change both of those. However, there's nothing actually *incorrect* with it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jason Bassford's comment, the second sentence is grammatically correct, although stylistically the sentence is not good.